# How to use local storage and delete when it is not needed

Tags: angularjs

Hi i am new to angular js and i am working around anglarjs local storage technique so that data persist on refresh. 
 Is there any way i can delete the local storage all in one and Also assign the scope storage to a model and use the model in html than $storage.id. I m very new and please share and help me. Thank

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<title>
</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-local-storage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.js"> </script>
<script>
var myApp=angular.module("myApp",['ngStorage','ngRoute']);
myApp.controller('myAppCtrl', ['$scope','$localStorage','$location', function($scope,$localStorage,$location){

    $scope.$storage=$localStorage.$default({
        myname:"",
        myid:"",
        mynumber:"",
    });
    $scope.add=function()
    {
    alert("asdsd")
    delete $scope.$storage.myid;
    delete $scope.$storage.myname;
    delete $scope.$storage.mynumber;
    $location.path("/add");
    } }]);

    myApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'search.html',
        controller:'myAppCtrl'
      }).
      when('/add',{
        templateUrl:'add.html',
        controller:'myAppCtrl'
      }).
       otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
   }]);
</script>
</head>
<body >
<div ng-view>
```

and my template is given below.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="search.html">
<button ng-click="add();"> add </button>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="add.html">
<div>
<input type="text" ng-model="$storage.myname"/></br>
<input type="text" ng-model="$storage.myid"/></br>
<input type="number" ng-model="$storage.mynumber"/></br>
<button ng-click="submit();"> submit </button>
<button ng-click="edit();"> view button </button>
</div>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use `$localStorage.$reset();` it will delete all your data from localStorage

Answer (score 1):

To delete local storage all in one , use $localStorage.clearAll().

To manually add a key / value pair to local storage, use $localStorage.add('id', $scope.id). Or, to bind to a scope variable directly, use $localStorage.bind($scope, 'id', id).

To get the value from local storage, use $localStorage.get('id').

The documentation on the GitHub ReadMe explains this: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage